# Как правильно написать условие переменная int не равна double?

Tags: c#

Подскажите пожалуйста, как правильно написать условие, если пользователь ввел не верный тип переменной, например double (36.5) вместо int (365) то будет выводиться ошибка.
сначала идет такой код

```
Console.WriteLine("Введите трехзначное целое число: ");
int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

if(...)//вот здесь как правильно написать что с должно быть равно int или не равно double?
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели не верное число");
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`if(...)` - вот здесь у вас всегда будет `int`, потому что `int c`, но выше будет исключение, там где `Convert`.

Решить можно двумя способами.

#### int.TryParse()

```cs
Console.Write("Введите трехзначное целое число: ");
if (int.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out int c)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Вы ввели число {c}");
}
else
{
    Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели неверное число");
}
```

#### try-catch

```cs
Console.Write("Введите трехзначное целое число: ");
try
{
    int c = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine($"Вы ввели число {c}");
}
catch
{
    Console.WriteLine("Вы ввели неверное число");
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое